# How to create an organised association that is project oriented?

Tags: rules-and-policies, communication

A group of youngsters (age average of 20 years) would like to establish an organisation that makes projects into reality. The question would be: What kind of structure would be the best to manage this organisation of about 32 people with different talents and specialties varying from tech to management?

I'd like examples of professional organizations that are project oriented and handle a lot of projects at the same time. I'd like our organization to be able to adapt to changes in the social scene in addition to changes in our economic state. I would also like to know a way to get us heavy sponsors.

Comment: It may be easier to answer this if you break out the individual questions.  How to get sponsors and how to structure the organization are two very, very different questions.

Comment: Is the idea to have everybody (or most people) working on any given project, or is this more of an "incubator" where people are working on different projects but doing so together and sometimes collaborating?

Comment: Do you plan to earn money with it? Commercial or charity? You should take a look [here](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/recruiting-sponsors-for-a-community-gathering/1314#1314) for the sponsoring related part of your question.

Comment: I'd like to structure the organization and also get sponsors, and no, it's not to gain money from it, it's a university club!

Comment: It's more of an "incubator", with people working on different projects and reporting to a comittee supervising the whole thing !

Answer (score 1):

For an organization of 32 people with diverse talents and specialties, a flexible and adaptive structure would be best suited to manage multiple projects simultaneously. Consider adopting a matrix organizational structure or a hybrid approach.

1. Matrix Organizational Structure: In this structure, team members are grouped by both function and project. This allows for effective communication and collaboration between functional and project teams. Team members can have multiple roles and be part of various projects based on their skills and expertise.

Examples of project-oriented organizations that use a matrix structure:

- Engineering and construction firms, such as Bechtel and Fluor Corporation.
- Management consulting companies, such as McKinsey & Company and Boston Consulting Group.

2. Hybrid Organizational Structure: This structure combines elements of functional, divisional, and matrix structures. It allows the organization to leverage the benefits of each type while mitigating potential downsides.

Examples of project-oriented organizations that use a hybrid structure:

- Technology companies, such as Google and Apple, that have a mix of functional, divisional, and project-based teams.
- Creative agencies and marketing firms that work on multiple client projects while maintaining functional departments.

To ensure adaptability, you can also consider implementing agile project management methodologies, such as Scrum or Kanban. These methods prioritize flexibility, collaboration, and iterative development.

To attract heavy sponsors, consider the following strategies:

1. Develop a strong value proposition: Clearly articulate the benefits your organization provides and how your projects create value for sponsors.
2. Build a track record of success: Execute projects efficiently and effectively to demonstrate competence and gain credibility.
3. Network strategically: Attend industry conferences, events, and seminars to connect with potential sponsors and partners.
4. Leverage digital platforms: Use social media, crowdfunding, and other online platforms to raise awareness and engage potential sponsors.
5. Create a professional sponsorship package: Develop a well-designed presentation or document that outlines the benefits and opportunities for sponsors, including different sponsorship tiers, project visibility, and potential ROI.
6. Collaborate with established organizations: Partner with well-known companies or organizations to increase your credibility and gain access to a wider network of potential sponsors.

Remember to tailor your approach to your target sponsors and their specific interests or industries. By demonstrating your organization's value, adaptability, and ability to execute projects effectively, you can attract the financial support you need to bring your projects to life.